# Magento2 issue cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Invalid argument

Tags: magento2

I use magento 2 blank and when I trying to apply a new theme I see this message

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Directory "D:/wamp64/www/magento-2/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Invalid argument

Comment: check my answer and apply it.

Answer (score 6):

Giving full control (read/write/execute) to var and pub directory solved this issue for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Or, you may also try running the command using sudo.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Also, try clearing cache.

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use this command in windows sudo chmod -R 777 var pub

Comment: You can install "Cygwin" and then use chmod -R 777 var

Comment: DON'T change directory permissions to 777. If you have to do this, your server is wrongly configured.

Comment: giving permission 777 is not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue. Kindly provide the necessary permissions to pub/ and var/ directories.

For more info, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html